# Hadamard product (Schur product) in $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, hilbert-spaces

Let's consider the separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H} = L^2[0,1]$ of square-integrable functions on the interval $[0,1]$ with orthonormal basis $(e_j)$. For $x,y \in \mathcal{H}$, the Hadamard product of $x$ and $y$ is defined to be $(x\,\odot\,y)(t)\,\colon= x(t)y(t)$ for all $t\in [0,1].$ I assume that $x, y$ are chosen such that $x \odot y \in \mathcal{H}.$

1. Is there any literature about such Hadamard products (instead of Hadamard Products for matrices)?
2. Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}_{\Omega}, \textbf{P})$ be a probability space, $(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{A_H})$ a measurable space and $X,Y\colon \Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ two random variables with $\textbf{E}||X||^2_{\mathcal{H}}, \textbf{E}||Y||^2_{\mathcal{H}} < \infty$ (hence $X\odot Y \in \mathcal{H}\;\textbf{P}$-almost-surely (a.s.) because of Cauchy Schwarz Inequality). If there is no proper subspace $U \subsetneq \mathcal{H}$ such that $X \in U\;\textbf{P}$-a.s.  and $Y \in U\;\textbf{P}$-a.s.. Then there is no linear subspace $U$ of $\mathcal{H}$ with $U \subsetneq \mathcal{H}$ such that $X \odot Y \in U,$ too?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The pointwise product of two square-integrable functions need not be square-integable. On $[0,1]$, a standard example would be given by $x(t) = y(t) = 1/\sqrt{t}$. So you might want to clarify your question accordingly. Also, the existence of a subspace $U$ as in item 2 cannot be excluded purely by looking at what happens on one particular basis only.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question. So basically I am not allowed to transform my basis in some way, such that it's not a constraint!?

Comment: Your "product" $\odot$ still doesn't make sense, since the pointwise product of two square-integrable functions need not be square-integrable. This has nothing to do with random variables and already occurs in the deterministic setting. In other words, the problem is actually in your first paragraph.

Comment: Embarrassingly, my counterexample $x(t) = y(t) = 1/\sqrt{t}$ is bogus in the sense that $1/\sqrt{t}$ isn't even square-integrable itself. But $x(t) = y(t) = t^{-1/3}$ will do: it's a square-integrable function on $[0,1]$ whose square isn't square-integrable. Therefore your "Hadamard product" isn't well-defined.

Comment: It's not embarrasing - I was nodding, when I read your comment, since I thought of integrability instead of square-integrability as well ;).

Comment: But, I still think that $X \odot Y$ is at least $\textbf{P}$-a.s. well defined:

$\textbf{E}||X||^2_{\mathcal{H}}, \textbf{E}||Y||^2_{\mathcal{H}} < \infty$ implies $||X||^2_{\mathcal{H}}, ||Y||^2_{\mathcal{H}} < \infty \,\textbf{P}$-a.s. and Cauchy Schwarz Inequality (in $\mathcal{H}$ and in $L^2$ endowed with $\textbf{P})$ yields to $\textbf{E}\langle X, Y\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} \leq \textbf{E}||X||_{\mathcal{H}}||Y||_{\mathcal{H}} \leq \sqrt{\textbf{E}||X||^2_{\mathcal{H}}\textbf{E}||Y||^2_{\mathcal{H}}} < \infty.$

Comment: What you seem to be showing there is that the scalar product is well-defined on functions $X,Y:\Omega\to\mathcal{H}$, but this has nothing to do with your Hadamard product. It's usually a good idea to check a statement in the degenerate cases. In your situation, this means that you should check what happens when $\Omega$ has only one element, i.e. in the deterministic case.

Comment: Now I know what u mean..., I just work with rv's, so I wasn't interested in the purely deterministic setting in the beginning, which I edited to: if the pointwise product exist.

But for rv's, since $\langle X, Y \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} \colon= \int X(t)Y(t)\text{d}t$ at least the pointwise product $X \odot Y \in \mathcal{H}$ should exist $\textbf{P}$-a.s., isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40053/discussion-between-obriareos-and-tobias-fritz).

Comment: Any hints left? :-)